# How to find the number of strings of length N that can be formed by using the characters A, B, and C only that do not have "ABC" as a substring?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A, B, and C can be used any number of times in the string. This problem appeared in a programming contest which is already over. http://www.codechef.com/problems/CDSW152

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we let $x_n$ be the number of admissible strings of length $n$, we have initial conditions $x_0=1$ (empty string); $x_1=3$; $x_2=9$.

For $n\ge 3$, we have that admissible strings of length $n$ consist of admissible strings of length $n-1$ with a letter $A$, $B$, or $C$ right appended; EXCEPT in the case that this results in a string ending in $ABC$.  These excepted cases come from admissible strings of length $n-1$ that end in $AB$ with the appended letter being $C$.  There are $x_{n-3}$ such strings.

So a recursion for this problem is $x_n=3x_{n-1}-x_{n-3}$ for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: This is better than my answer, because simpler.

Comment: "There are xn−3 such strings." Can you please give a small explanation for this.

Comment: These excepted strings come from $\dots AB$ (length $n-1$). There are $x_{n-3}$ such strings (living in the dots).

Comment: Can you also explain how to solve this without the recurrence relation. Using the inclusion-exclusion principle like someone had posted before. Thanks.

Comment: @StupidMan: But this is much simpler than inclusion-exclusion!

Comment: @TonyK Yes it's much simpler but I have only seen some very simple applications of the inclusion exclusion principle so I wanted to see how to apply it in this problem.

Comment: @StupidMan: Here's the formula for inclusion-exclusion (I think): Let $t=\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\rfloor$.  (So $t$ is the greatest number of times the substring $ABC$ could appear in $n$ letters).  Then the number admissible strings of length $n$ is $\sum_{k=0}^t (-1)^k \cdot {n-2k\choose k}\cdot 3^{n-2k}$. In each term, $k$ is the minimum number of $ABC$ substrings occurring (for each such $k$ there are an additional $n-3k$ characters $A$, $B$, or $C$ to place, along with the $k$ occurrences of $ABC$).

Answer (score 0):

For $k = 1,\ldots,N$, compute:

- $S_k =$ the number of valid strings of length $k$ that end in $A$;
- $T_k =$ the number of valid strings of length $k$ that end in $AB$;
- $U_k =$ the number of all other valid strings of length $k$.

You can do this by finding expressions for $S_k,T_k,$ and $U_k$ in terms of $S_{k-1},T_{k-1}$, and $U_{k-1}$.

Now the answer is just $S_N+T_N+U_N$.